# How to delete nested array elements in mongo Db

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, nested-attributes

"How to delete a single element from the nested array 'accounts' from the structure (Shown on the image also)  of mongo db. Can I do it using $pull method? Any one know please share your Ideas".

```
 "associatedAccounts" : [ 
        {
            "organizationId" : "5808ba773fe315441b9e0a9e",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5808bc0c3fe315441b9e0b1a"),
            "accounts" : [ 
                "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa7", 
                "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa8", 
                "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa1"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "organizationId" : "5808ba773fe315441b9e0a9f",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5808bc0c3fe315441b9e0b1b"),
            "accounts" : [ 
                "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa3", 
                "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa2", 
                "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa5", 
                "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa6"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

,[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

You can delete on the base of `_id` because Id is uniquely identify in Mongodb

```
 db.stores.update(
 {_id:id  },  //set accounts Id which you want to update
 {$pull:{
        "associatedAccounts":{
                  "_id"accountsId // the unique _id from the objects in arrray  
                   }
        }
 })
```

accountsId will be unique id from associatedAccounts i.e _id of each object which is present in this array.

`$pull` will remove that perticular object whose id matches to the query.

Comment: This is an incorrect method and it will not work for the scenario that I have mentioned